# AuthorizeAttribute at asp.net MVC cannot write log to file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I try to customize AuthorizeAttribute for authentication at restful service. I want to write information into a log file. But it didn't work. I don't see any log file at my log path. (I have enable permission to IIS_USER)

Also, I even found that if AuthorizeCore return false, my test client can still get the result. Is somewhere in my code wrong? Or something I misunderstand how AuthorizeAttribute work?

PS. I also found that if I switch log part to ApiController it will work! It's so weird!

**Filter**

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mvctest\logs\Trace.log", true, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            IEnumerable<String> header = httpContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("User");
            foreach (String str in header)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(str);
            }
            sw.Flush();
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

**ApiController**

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values

    [MyAuthorizeAttribute]
    public List<String> Get()
    {
        return new List<String> { "Success", "Get" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [MyAuthorizeAttribute]
    public String Get(int id)
    {   
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

**TestClient**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/mvctest/api/values/5");
            request.Headers.Add("User", "Darkurvivor");
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                String data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two `AuthorizeAttribute`s.  One for WebApi and one for MVC.   WebApi uses `System.Web.http.AuthorizeAttribute`, while MVC uses `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`.  You canoot use one with the other.  So, no.  It's not weird at all.

Comment: Thanks! I found that i mix up System.Web.http.AuthorizeAttribute and System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute! Now it works for me while changing to System.Web.http.AuthorizeAttribute!!